# print output of user-defined function in awk gives unexpected token error

Tags: function, variables, awk, printing

I wanted to flexibly print the output of two small awk to bash pipes, which are using variables (they worked originally). I initially thought I could store the whole command as variable itself, but for one it did not work and apparently ([store awk command in a variable of bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998580/store-awk-command-in-a-variable-of-bash-script)) it is not a good idea. So I wrote two functions, but I'm getting an "unexpected token" near "done", but it is formatted as in the link above.

Where is my mistake?

```
for coverage_file in */*.cov
do
    #gene_count=$(awk '{print $5}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l) #this is apparently not a good idea
    #contig_count=$(awk '{print $1}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l) #this is apparently not a good idea
    cmd_gene() { awk '{print $5}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l }
    cmd_contig() { awk '{print $1}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l }
    cmd_gene $coverage_file
    cmd_contig $coverage_file
    #print "we found", $gene_count, "genes on ",$contig_count" contigs
done
```

the cov files look like this:

```
k141_85332.3 4119 19 A5 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 19 A5 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 28 A1 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 28 A1 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 8 A2 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 8 A2 phnM_031
k141_88684 267 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 268 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 269 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 270 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 271 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 272 5 B10 phnM_032
```

EDIT: this includes the accepted answer + a possible way to print it plainly:

```
#!/bin/bash

#define variables
gene="phnM"
threshold="5"

#define functions
cmd_gene() { awk '{print $5}' $1 |sort | uniq -c | wc -l ; } #semicolon is important here!
cmd_contig() { awk '{print $1}' $1 |sort | uniq -c | wc -l ; } #semicolon is important here!

#loop over files and print results (would be prettier with printf)
for coverage_file in */*.cov
do
    echo $gene" was found" $(cmd_gene "$coverage_file") "times on" $(cmd_contig "$coverage_file")" contigs with minimum coverage of" $threshold in $coverage_file
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
phnM was found 67 times on 65 contigs with minimum coverage of 5 in phnm/test.cov
phnM was found 3 times on 2 contigs with minimum coverage of 5 in test/test.cov
```

Comment: The unexpected token error is coming because when you define a function, the `}` has to be on it's own line or preceded by `;`.  E.g.: `cmd_contig() { awk '{print $1}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l; }`

Comment: hm ja that was embarrassing ;-) thanks. Do you wanna post it as an answer?

Comment: Not even close to embarrassing; sure, I'll add as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected token error is coming because when you define a function, the } has to be on it's own line or preceded by ;.

Also, since you're using `$coverage_file` in the definition of the function, you don't have to pass it.

```
for coverage_file in */*.cov
do
    cmd_gene() { awk '{print $5}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l; }
    cmd_contig() { awk '{print $1}' $coverage_file |sort | uniq -c | wc -l; }
    cmd_gene 
    cmd_contig 
    #print "we found", $gene_count, "genes on ",$contig_count" contigs
done
```

If you want to define the functions outside the for loop, you would use `$1` (not to be confused with awk's $1) and pass `$coverage_file` like you were doing before.

**EDIT**: Example of above

```
$ cat a.sh
cmd_gene() { awk '{print $5}' $1 |sort | uniq -c | wc -l; }
cmd_contig() { awk '{print $1}' $1 |sort | uniq -c | wc -l; }

for coverage_file in */*.cov
do
    cmd_gene $coverage_file
    cmd_contig $coverage_file
done

$ ls */*.cov
bf/a.cov

$ cat */*.cov
k141_85332.3 4119 19 A5 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 19 A5 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 28 A1 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 28 A1 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 8 A2 phnM_031
k141_85332.3 4119 8 A2 phnM_031
k141_88684 267 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 268 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 269 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 270 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 271 5 B10 phnM_032
k141_88684 272 5 B10 phnM_032

$ sh a.sh
       2
       2
```

Comment: Consider `awk '{genes[$5]; contigs[$1]} END{print length(genes) ORS length(contigs)}' "$coverage_file"` - it'll give the same output as both functions together without multiple calls to external commands, pipes, etc. and of course you don't actually need a shell loop at all, you can do the whole thing with a single call to a small, trivial awk script.

Answer (score 1):

@jas answered your question so stick with that, the following is just a generally better way to do what you're trying to do that's too big/formatted to be appropriate for a comment:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    gene = "phnM"
    threshold = "5"
}
{
    genes[$5]
    contigs[$1]
}
ENDFILE {
    printf "%s was found %d times on %d contigs with minimum coverage of %d in %s\n",
        gene, length(genes), length(contigs), threshold, FILENAME
    delete genes
    delete contigs
}
' */*.cov
```

The above uses GNU awk for ENDFILE but it's a trivial change to make it work for other awks if necessary:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    gene = "phnM"
    threshold = "5"
}
FNR==1 { prt() }
{
    genes[$5]
    contigs[$1]
}
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if (fname != "") {
        printf "%s was found %d times on %d contigs with minimum coverage of %d in %s\n",
            gene, length(genes), length(contigs), threshold, fname
        delete genes
        delete contigs
    }
    fname = FILENAME
}
' */*.cov
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for **some** of the reasons to avoid shell loops when manipulating text.

Comment: thanks Ed, this is very impressive, but I don't see how it works? Why do you use the prt() function two times, one time only at the first record of the first file?

Comment: In GNU awk we have the ENDFILE construct that is true when we reach the end of each input file. So if we want to print some information after processing each file, we simply put that in the ENDFILE block. In other awks we don't have that so we need to emulate it.

Comment: FNR==1 is a condition that's true when the first line of each file is read so I can print info about the **previous** file in the FNR==1 block for the **current** file. That leaves us still needing to do something when done reading the final input file so what we do in the FNR==1 section has to be duplicated in the END section, typically by a common function (`prt()` in this case) called from both FNR==1 and END blocks.

Comment: ah I see, so if the `*/*.cov` part would find 20 input files, the results of the first 19 files would be printed by the `FNR==1 { prt() }` and the 20th result comes from the `END { prt() }`, right? Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: btw note that there's an edge case where use of ENDFILE and the non-gawk FNR==1/END workaround won't produce the same output and that's if you can have empty input files in the middle of the list. ENDFILE will produce info about the empty file, the other approach won't.